# How do I keep drawing on image after window resize in PyQt?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

I have written a code to draw a rectangle on an image in a **QGraphicsView** but if I resize the image, for example full screen, the position of the rectangle becomes misplaced. Is there any way to fix this?
I think one possible solution is to align the image every time in top left corner but I cannot give 2 arguments in **setAlignment()**.

Here is the code:(the buttons are just for show atm)

```
class MyWidget(QWidget):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    self.b1 = QPushButton('Next Image')
    self.b2 = QPushButton('Crop')
    self.b3 = QPushButton('Clear')

    self.view = GraphicsView()
    h_box = QHBoxLayout()
    v_box = QVBoxLayout()
    v_box.addWidget(self.b1)
    v_box.addWidget(self.b2)
    v_box.addWidget(self.b3)
    h_box.addWidget(self.view)
    h_box.addLayout(v_box)
    self.setLayout(h_box)
    #self.resize(800, 800)
    self.setWindowTitle("Super Duper Cropper")

    self.show()



class GraphicsView(QGraphicsView):

def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.setScene(QGraphicsScene())

    self.item = QGraphicsPixmapItem(QPixmap('test.jpg'))
    self.scene().addItem(self.item)



def mousePressEvent(self, event):
    self.xi = event.x()
    self.yi = event.y()

def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
    self.xf = event.x()
    self.yf = event.y()
    self.draw_rect()


def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
    self.xf = event.x()
    self.yf = event.y()
    self.draw_rect()

def draw_rect(self):
    self.scene().removeItem(self.item)
    self.scene().addItem(self.item)

    self.scene().addRect(self.xi, self.yi, self.xf-self.xi, self.yf-self.yi, pen=QPen(QColor(51, 153, 255), 2,
                        Qt.SolidLine), brush=QBrush(QColor(0, 255, 0, 40)))



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWidget()
    window.show()
    app.aboutToQuit.connect(app.deleteLater)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the following errors:

- The coordinates of the scene are different from the coordinates of the view, so you must use the `mapToScene()` method if you want to establish the right position of the rectangle.
- *Why do you add and remove the items?* the best thing is to reuse
- You want the position of the rectangle to be relative to the `QGraphicsPixmapItem`, so the rectangle has to be a child of the `QGraphicsPixmapItem`.

Using the above we obtain the following:

```
class GraphicsView(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setScene(QGraphicsScene())
        self.item = QGraphicsPixmapItem(QPixmap('test.jpg'))
        self.scene().addItem(self.item)
        self.rect_item = QGraphicsRectItem(QRectF(), self.item)
        self.rect_item.setPen(QPen(QColor(51, 153, 255), 2, Qt.SolidLine))
        self.rect_item.setBrush(QBrush(QColor(0, 255, 0, 40)))

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.pi = self.mapToScene(event.pos())
        super().mousePressEvent(event)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        pf = self.mapToScene(event.pos())
        if (self.pi - pf).manhattanLength() > QApplication.startDragDistance():
            self.pf = pf
            self.draw_rect()
        super().mouseMoveEvent(event)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        pf = self.mapToScene(event.pos())
        if (self.pi - pf).manhattanLength() > QApplication.startDragDistance():
            self.pf = pf
            self.draw_rect()
        super().mouseReleaseEvent(event)

    def draw_rect(self):
        r = QRectF(self.pi, self.pf).normalized()
        r = self.rect_item.mapFromScene(r).boundingRect()
        self.rect_item.setRect(r)
```

Comment: I was removing and adding because the picture was not updating the way I wrote it. I'm still a beginner at this. Thank you very much! It works now

Comment: @DanielT. 
If my answer helps you, do not forget to mark it as correct, if you do not know how to do it, review the [tour], that is the best way to thank.